# Determine $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq \frac{n}{2})$

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$ are independent and uniformly distributed (on $[0,1]$) random variables. Determine $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq \frac{n}{2})$

My thoughts were the following:

I suppose I can say that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq \frac{n}{2}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq \frac{1}{2}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\overline X_n \leq \frac{1}{2}\right)$$
And isn't $\overline X_n$ also uniformly distributed? So the probability equals $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: You can get the parentheses to adjust to their content by using `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @joriki: And also $\to$ with `\to`.

Answer (score 3):

No, $\overline{X_n}$ isn't uniformly distributed; but it's distributed symmetrically about $\frac12$, so you can nevertheless conclude that the probability is $\frac12$ even without the limit.

Comment: So what is the right way to go? I don't fully understand

Comment: If one is not comfortable thinking about this as intuitively as @joriki has described, we can also apply the Central Limit Theorem. In the limit, $\bar{X_n}$ will be distributed normally, and the mean of $\bar{X_n}$ will be $\mathbb{E}(X_i) = \frac{1}{2}.$ Thus, by the symmetry of the normal distribution, this probability would be $1/2.$

Comment: @Di-lemma: There's no more way to go. The statement is true by symmetry, even if you remove the limit. If you want to make the symmetry explicit, it's $X_i\to1-X_i$.

Comment: @David: I think you meant "normally" instead of "uniformly"? But it would be quite a detour to prove something using the central limit theorem when it's actually true without the limit.

Comment: @joriki Yes correct, I edited right away! Correct, but I believe (given the tags) that he is in an elementary probability class and learning about limit theorems.

Comment: @David: Then it's a bad exercise :-)

Comment: @David You're correct, I'm currently learning about limit theorems